# Ignore Duplicates Using INSERT IGNORE in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a table in which a field is **Unique** and has some records in it. I need to insert some new records (some records may already exist in the table) without making the query fail.

In plain **MySQL**; I may write the query using the **IGNORE** keyword as **INSERT IGNORE ...**

How to specify **INSERT IGNORE** in **Zend Framework 2** DB

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this :

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Insert;

class InsertIgnore extends Insert
{
    /**
     * @var array Specification array
     */
    protected $specifications = [
        self::SPECIFICATION_INSERT => 'INSERT IGNORE INTO %1$s (%2$s) VALUES (%3$s)',
        self::SPECIFICATION_SELECT => 'INSERT IGNORE INTO %1$s %2$s %3$s',
    ];
}
```

In practice

```
//$action = $sql->insert(); // Before
$action = new InsertIgnore($sql->getTable()); // After
$action->values($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `\Zend\Db\Sql\Insert` you can create extended class and override `getSqlString(...)`:

---

`\src\MyNamespace\Zend\Db\Sql\Insert.php`

```php
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Zend\Db\Sql;

class Insert extends \Zend\Db\Sql\Insert {
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $ignore = false;

    public function getSqlString(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface $adapterPlatform = null) {
        if ($this->ignore !== true) {
            return parent::getSqlString($adapterPlatform);
        }
        return preg_replace('/^INSERT/', 'INSERT IGNORE', parent::getSqlString($adapterPlatform), 1);
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```php
$insert = new \MyNamespace\Zend\Db\Sql\Insert();
$insert->ignore = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still do that in plain MySQL if you like.

> $sql = "INSERT... ";

get adapter like this if you are using tablegateway or define an adapter [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html)

```
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();

$resultset = $adapter->query($sql,array());
$rowData= $resultset->getAffectedRows();
```

Comment: Thanks @dixromos98. I'm using the query method at present. Is there any native methods in ZF2 to perform an INSERT IGNORE query?

Comment: Can you modify the answer for an INSERT query? As the question is about an INSERT query; it would be better for others viewing the answer.

Comment: I had a look around but it seems that insert ignore is not supported. The work around logic that is being used as i saw in tutorials is to check if a primary key exist and then perform an update to that row. That is if you do not want the plain query